# c# line chart. Why does my line go to 0 instead of just staying at the last point?

Tags: c#, charts

So i made a button and when you press it displays a graph of the arrays, but it goes to 0 when its finished.

```
private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= period; i++)
        {
            xos[i] = i+1;
            yos[i] = pot[i];
            listBox1.Items.Add(xos[i]);
            listBox1.Items.Add("y " + yos[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= period; i++)
        {
         x2os[i] = i + 1;
         y2os[i] = pot2[i];
         listBox2.Items.Add(x2os[i]);
         listBox2.Items.Add("y "+y2os[i]);

        }
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
        chart1.Series["Potražnja"].Points.DataBindXY(xos, yos);
        chart1.Series["Predviđanje"].Points.DataBindXY(x2os,y2os);
    }
```

Here is a photo of chart

[image]

Comment: Here is a photo of the chart ( i cant upload it) http://prntscr.com/6mvzjx

Comment: What is the length of `x2os` and `y2os`? Is their length different from `period + 1`?

Comment: The length is user defined, and its the same as period +1. and xos and yos are just "period". And sorry i don't know how to format.
EDIT: i put period+1 in the for loop, where x2os and y2os are. And its oke now

Comment: But one more question, how do i stop it at x=5, like you can see in the picture, so it doesn't go to x=6?
EDIT: and what to do that the yellow line begins at x=4, and not x=3?

Comment: If you use `period + 1` in the loop then the array lengths have to be `period + 2`. The data series is as long as the arrays, so to make it end sooner you should make the arrays shorter.

Comment: if you look at this picture: http://prntscr.com/6mwgdq
i put period as 5 (so it should go from 1 to 5, not 6), and if you look at the code (the first loop), what should i change? pot[] is 15 long when defined, but when its used its like the period so 5 long in this case. and xos is the same.

Comment: When you set `period` to 5, the loop will go from 0 to 5 and produce coordinates from 1 to 6.

Comment: Now it looks like this, i really don't get it, i have been playing with this the pas 4-5h. http://prntscr.com/6mwre0

Comment: That looks good, except that the `period` value is too high. You should use `period = 5` for five coordinates.

Comment: I did use period=5 and again it went to 0 after x=5. It just wont stay at the end what ever i do.

Comment: Have you changed the length of the arrays to 5?

Comment: You should make the arrays for the coordinates only as long as they need to be for the coordinates. Right now they contain the five coordinates from `pot`, then ten more coordinates at `0,0`.

Comment: whoa ty it worked :), now just one more thing how can i make the yellow line go from 3, not 2. Picture: http://prntscr.com/6mxroo

Comment: I added code for that below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create the arrays before you know how long they need to be, just declare the references:

```
public double[] xos;
public double[] yos;
public double[] y2os;
public double[] x2os;
```

Then when you use them, create the actual arrays:

```
private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    xos = new double[period + 1];
    yos = new double[period + 1];
    x2os = new double[period + 1];
    y2os = new double[period + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= period; i++)
    {
        xos[i] = i+1;
        yos[i] = pot[i];
        listBox1.Items.Add(xos[i]);
        listBox1.Items.Add("y " + yos[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= period; i++)
    {
         x2os[i] = i + 1;
         y2os[i] = pot2[i];
         listBox2.Items.Add(x2os[i]);
         listBox2.Items.Add("y "+y2os[i]);

    }
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
    chart1.Series["Potražnja"].Points.DataBindXY(xos, yos);
    chart1.Series["Predviđanje"].Points.DataBindXY(x2os,y2os);
 }
```

To make the yellow line skip the first zero values, you would need to check for those first, and then create the arrays:

```
    var start = 0;
    while (start <= period && pot2[start] == 0) {
      start++;
    }
    x2os = new double[period - start + 1];
    y2os = new double[period - start + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= period - start; i++)
    {
         x2os[i] = start + i + 1;
         y2os[i] = pot2[start + i];
         listBox2.Items.Add(x2os[i]);
         listBox2.Items.Add("y "+y2os[i]);

    }
```

Comment: hmm, now it skips the zeros but still draws the line from 0. Picture: http://prntscr.com/6mxyz6
And i removed +1 when i create xos and yos because they ahve to be long as period and it works, now just the yellow line.

Comment: @cymenx: Right, you need to put the coordinates from index 0 in the arrays, and make the arrays shorter. I corrected the code above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)). I just edited x2os[i] = i + (start+1); and it works perfectly thanks again :D

Comment: @cymenx: Yes you are right, I forgot to adjust the x coordinate.